# How do I add and print a image in the console in python with visual studio?

Tags: python

I dont know what to import and how to do this. How do I print and add a image in python.

I have tried nothing im just looking for suggestions.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

In the console it's impossible, but you can use OpenCV, PIL, or matplotlib to display images.

With OpenCV you can display the pixel value in the console:

[image: image as matrix with opencv]

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in image manipulation check out [Pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/tutorial.html). It's an image manipulation/processing library.

You can install it with:

```
python -m pip install Pillow
```

To load an image and show it use this:

```py
from PIL import Image

im = Image.open("image.png")

im.show()
```

*For more examples and information check out the [official documentation](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html).*